# PHP+XHTML+CSS+JS - Syntax Highlight

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Does anyone know a website where you can paste some code and it generates highlighted source code? As HTML, like Geshi, with span tags with color styles on them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[QuickHighlighter.com](http://quickhighlighter.com) works pretty well.

Comment: works, but it generates separate css styles. I need the generated code to have inline styles so I can paste it inside a documentation i'm building :)